# Why can we be heard thousands of miles away?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I quote from *'The Feynman Lectures on Physics'* :

'It seems a miracle that someone talking in Europe can, with mere electrical influences, be heard thousands of miles away in Los Angeles. How is it possible? **It is because the fields do not vary as the inverse square, but only inversely as the first power of the distance**'.

I do not understand this reasoning as to me it makes reference to the same concept throughout all the bold sentence: The inverse-square law.

Could you delve into this reasoning?

Comment: "_inversely as the first power_" means $1/r$. This is not the same as "inverse square" which means $1/r^2$.

Comment: It's a distinction between the rate at which the magnitude of static fields due to localized sources (such as the electric field due to a charge, or the gravitational field due to a mass) drop off with distance, which is like $1/r^2$, and the rate at which the magnitudes of the fields in electromagnetic waves drop off, which is like $1/r$.